# Project files can't see library

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-pub

There are many libraries I use every day from pub and they work. But today I run into a problem with `qr_code_scanner`. After installing it with `flutter pub add qr_code_scanner` and running `flutter pub get`, I get in code:

[image: Error]

Same with auto import for classes from this file like `QRViewController`. What I also did is running `flutter upgrade`, `flutter clean` and everything else that came to my mind - still getting this error with that package.

Any other thoughts how can I solve it?

Comment: which version of flutter are you using?

Comment: I ran `flutter upgrade` so the latest as for now: `Flutter 3.0.2` and `Dart 2.17.3`. Official docs in change log says `Breaking changes: Minimum Flutter version is now Flutter 3.0.0 (Dart 2.17.0).` for latest 1.0.0 version so there is no other way to not upgrade it

Answer (score 0):

Some of the packages you are using are upgraded to flutter3 and some are still Flutter version < 3. Which is why you might be facing an issue. If you are trying to build an older project I would recommend you to downgrade your package versions which is compatible with flutter < 3 and use flutter version < 3. If you are adding any packages through pub add you might get an error if the pub get is not resolved. Please check the same in terminal.

Comment: So what you're trying to say I should upgrade all the packages to flutter >= 3 in order for this particular library to work? Or you're trying to suggest other solution?

Comment: Yeah, if you have all packages available for version > 3 then you can use flutter version3. Else its better to downgrade packages to versions that run on flutter version less than 3 and use flutter sdk which is less than 3

Comment: Is there any way to bulk upgrade it all so it all works under v3+ ?

Comment: no unless all the packages that you are using supports version 3.0+

Comment: So what I've done is downgrading Flutter version to 2.13 by switching to older git branch in my installation folder, adjusted package versions for all libraries so they work < 3 but the problem stays the same -> only this library has an error on import and can't access any classes from it. What in this scenario?

Comment: What's the error that you are getting?

Comment: The error is that it looks like it doesn't see this library, so whenever I put import statement it's highlighted red like on the screenshot above in question

Comment: That's because pub get wasn't resolved

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who will have the same issue, I found a workaround. I've also tried few other libraries that beside the fact was installed couldn't access them from anywhere in code. 
So after all every pub.dev lib is just the code right? You can download the source file and add it into your `lib` folder. Well, you have to upgrade it manually if needed but at the end it works and that's the main goal!
EDIT:
Another possible solution, as I found out, I did reset my Mac, upgraded environment (VS Code), done `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` and looks like it's working as it should without mentioned workaround so probably the issue was around the coding environment rather than with Flutter and fetched libraries.